# Multiple bootstrap accordions with collapse other when clicked on one accordion

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, accordion

I tried the following code and everything is fine except the `FontAwesome` icons. I tried to find some solution on Google, but I couldn't find the solution that I'm looking for.

When I click on one of the accordion the other accordion should be collapsed and the current clicked accordion should be open, and at the same time the fa icon should be changed depending on the accordion position.

Here is what I have tried so far [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/designercaptain/2shgcoLz/)

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

     $(".accordion-body").on("shown", function (evt) {
         setIcon(evt.target, true);
     });

     $(".accordion-body").on("hidden", function (evt) {
         setIcon(evt.target, false);
     });

     $(".accordion-body").collapse("hide");
     $("#collapse-faq-1").collapse("show");


 });

 $('.accordion-toggle').click(function(event) {
 var id = '#'+ event.currentTarget.firstElementChild.id;
    if('class == fa-chevron-down'){
     $(id).removeClass('fa-chevron-down');
     $(id).addClass('fa-close');
 }else{
  $(id).removeClass('fa-close');
     $(id).addClass('fa-chevron-down');
 }
});

$(function () {

    var active = true;

    $('#collapse-init').click(function () {
        if (active) {
            active = false;
            $('.panel-collapse').collapse('show');
            $('.panel-title').attr('data-toggle', '');
            $(this).text('Enable accordion behavior');
        } else {
            active = true;
            $('.panel-collapse').collapse('hide');
            $('.panel-title').attr('data-toggle', 'collapse');
            $(this).text('Disable accordion behavior');
        }
    });
    
    $('#accordion').on('show.bs.collapse', function () {
        if (active) $('#accordion .in').collapse('hide');
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="accordion" id="accordion">
    <div class="accordion-group items">
        <div class="accordion-heading">
            <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse-faq-1">
                <i id="indicator-1" class="fa fa-chevron-down pull-right"></i> 
                Question
            </a>
        </div>
        <div id="collapse-faq-1" class="accordion-body collapse in">
            <div class="accordion-inner">
                <p>
              Inner content
             </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="accordion-group items">
        <div class="accordion-heading">
            <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse-faq-2">
                <i id="indicator-2" class="fa fa-chevron-down pull-right"></i> 
                Question
            </a>
        </div>
        <div id="collapse-faq-2" class="accordion-body collapse in">
            <div class="accordion-inner">
             <p>
              Inner content
             </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="accordion-group items">
        <div class="accordion-heading">
            <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse-faq-3">
                <i id="indicator-3" class="fa fa-chevron-down pull-right"></i> 
                Question
            </a>
        </div>
        <div id="collapse-faq-3" class="accordion-body collapse in">
            <div class="accordion-inner">
                <p>
              Inner content
             </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="accordion-group items">
        <div class="accordion-heading">
            <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse-faq-4">
                <i id="indicator-4" class="fa fa-chevron-down pull-right"></i> 
                Question
            </a>
        </div>
        <div id="collapse-faq-4" class="accordion-body collapse in">
            <div class="accordion-inner">
                <p>
              Inner content
             </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="accordion-group items">
        <div class="accordion-heading">
            <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse-faq-5">
                <i id="indicator-5" class="fa fa-chevron-down pull-right"></i> 
                Question
            </a>
        </div>
        <div id="collapse-faq-5" class="accordion-body collapse in">
            <div class="accordion-inner">
                <p>
              Inner content
             </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="accordion-group items">
        <div class="accordion-heading">
            <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse-faq-6">
                <i id="indicator-6" class="fa fa-chevron-down pull-right"></i> 
                Question
            </a>
        </div>
        <div id="collapse-faq-6" class="accordion-body collapse in">
            <div class="accordion-inner">
             <p>
              Inner content
             </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="accordion-group items">
        <div class="accordion-heading WhiteBg" id="heads">
            <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse-faq-7">
                <i id="indicator-7" class="fa fa-chevron-down pull-right"></i> 
                Question
            </a>
        </div>
        <div id="collapse-faq-7" class="accordion-body collapse in">
            <div class="accordion-inner">
                <p>
              Inner content
             </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="accordion-group items">
        <div class="accordion-heading WhiteBg">
            <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse-faq-8">
                <i id="indicator-8" class="fa fa-chevron-down pull-right"></i> 
                Question
            </a>
        </div>
        <div id="collapse-faq-8" class="accordion-body collapse in">
            <div class="accordion-inner">
                <p>
              Inner content
             </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you didn't link the `bootstrap.min.js` file in your code. If you want to use bootstrap then you need to include its `bootstrap.min.css` file along with its `bootstrap.min.js` file to do all the stuff for you.

You need the following code to work as per on your requirement. By using `not(this)` it will gives you all the elements except the current clicked item. So that you can reset Fa Icons on all the other elements and apply specific Icon on your this element.

```
$('.accordion-toggle').click(function (event) {

    var $this = $(this);

    // It will reset all the other icons except the clicked item icon

    $('.accordion-toggle').not(this).children('i').removeClass('fa-close').addClass('fa-chevron-down');

    if ($this.children('i').hasClass('fa-chevron-down')) {

        $this.children('i').removeClass('fa-chevron-down').addClass('fa-close');

    } else {

        $this.children('i').removeClass('fa-close').addClass('fa-chevron-down');

    }
});
```

***[Here is working JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/vL1y32gu/1/)***

---

Below is the embedded snippet for your question.

```js
$(function () {


        $(document).ready(function () {

            $(".accordion-body").on("shown", function (evt) {
                setIcon(evt.target, true);
            });

            $(".accordion-body").on("hidden", function (evt) {
                setIcon(evt.target, false);
            });

            $(".accordion-body").collapse("hide");
            $("#collapse-faq-1").collapse("show");


        });

        $('.accordion-toggle').click(function (event) {

            var $this = $(this);

            // It will reset all the icons except the clicked (this) item.
            $('.accordion-toggle').not(this).children('i').removeClass('fa-close').addClass('fa-chevron-down');

            if ($this.children('i').hasClass('fa-chevron-down')) {
                
                $this.children('i').removeClass('fa-chevron-down').addClass('fa-close');
                
            } else {
                
                $this.children('i').removeClass('fa-close').addClass('fa-chevron-down');
                
            }
        });

        $(function () {

            var active = true;

            $('#collapse-init').click(function () {
                if (active) {
                    active = false;
                    $('.panel-collapse').collapse('show');
                    $('.panel-title').attr('data-toggle', '');
                    $(this).text('Enable accordion behavior');
                } else {
                    active = true;
                    $('.panel-collapse').collapse('hide');
                    $('.panel-title').attr('data-toggle', 'collapse');
                    $(this).text('Disable accordion behavior');
                }
            });

            $('#accordion').on('show.bs.collapse', function () {
                if (active) $('#accordion .in').collapse('hide');
            });

        });

    });
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="accordion" id="accordion">
    <div class="accordion-group items">
        <div class="accordion-heading">
            <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse-faq-1">
                <i id="indicator-1" class="fa fa-chevron-down pull-right"></i> 
                Question
            </a>
        </div>
        <div id="collapse-faq-1" class="accordion-body collapse in">
            <div class="accordion-inner">
                <p>
              Inner content
             </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="accordion-group items">
        <div class="accordion-heading">
            <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse-faq-2">
                <i id="indicator-2" class="fa fa-chevron-down pull-right"></i> 
                Question
            </a>
        </div>
        <div id="collapse-faq-2" class="accordion-body collapse in">
            <div class="accordion-inner">
             <p>
              Inner content
             </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="accordion-group items">
        <div class="accordion-heading">
            <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse-faq-3">
                <i id="indicator-3" class="fa fa-chevron-down pull-right"></i> 
                Question
            </a>
        </div>
        <div id="collapse-faq-3" class="accordion-body collapse in">
            <div class="accordion-inner">
                <p>
              Inner content
             </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="accordion-group items">
        <div class="accordion-heading">
            <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse-faq-4">
                <i id="indicator-4" class="fa fa-chevron-down pull-right"></i> 
                Question
            </a>
        </div>
        <div id="collapse-faq-4" class="accordion-body collapse in">
            <div class="accordion-inner">
                <p>
              Inner content
             </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="accordion-group items">
        <div class="accordion-heading">
            <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse-faq-5">
                <i id="indicator-5" class="fa fa-chevron-down pull-right"></i> 
                Question
            </a>
        </div>
        <div id="collapse-faq-5" class="accordion-body collapse in">
            <div class="accordion-inner">
                <p>
              Inner content
             </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="accordion-group items">
        <div class="accordion-heading">
            <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse-faq-6">
                <i id="indicator-6" class="fa fa-chevron-down pull-right"></i> 
                Question
            </a>
        </div>
        <div id="collapse-faq-6" class="accordion-body collapse in">
            <div class="accordion-inner">
             <p>
              Inner content
             </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="accordion-group items">
        <div class="accordion-heading WhiteBg" id="heads">
            <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse-faq-7">
                <i id="indicator-7" class="fa fa-chevron-down pull-right"></i> 
                Question
            </a>
        </div>
        <div id="collapse-faq-7" class="accordion-body collapse in">
            <div class="accordion-inner">
                <p>
              Inner content
             </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="accordion-group items">
        <div class="accordion-heading WhiteBg">
            <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse-faq-8">
                <i id="indicator-8" class="fa fa-chevron-down pull-right"></i> 
                Question
            </a>
        </div>
        <div id="collapse-faq-8" class="accordion-body collapse in">
            <div class="accordion-inner">
                <p>
              Inner content
             </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have updated my **[DEMO JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vL1y32gu/1/)** in the answer. Please visit it and I'm sure this is the solution that you are looking for.

Comment: You mean you want to change the background of the text Question  to grey when it is opened and change it back to white when the accordion is closed?

Comment: You can use `$this.css({ "background": "grey" });` in if block and `$this.css({ "background": "white" });` in else block. Also you need to add `$('.accordion-toggle').not(this).css({ "background": "white" });` to remove background from all the other questions, except **$(this)**
**[Here is the further updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vL1y32gu/2/)**